# What is the way to update to the next kernel?

Tags: kernel

So, I have problems with nouveau preventing from sleep. I decided to go with the newer kernel than officially available. Should I install kernel from Mainline PPA (I do know it's not real PPA)? If I do, will my kernel be replaced when matching (or newer) kernel is officially released? What is the way to get that effect (being in sync with official repos)?

**UPDATE** I would like not to go with completely automated newer kernel installation, like with `ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa` (I mean I don't want installed packages to be updated automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking if you install an updated mainline kernel today, will this be replaced in future by official kernel if there is a release with kernel version greater than this mainline kernel?

The answer is *NO*. Because each kernel is packaged independently and kernel's version number is part of the package name. That is why you can run multiple kernels in the same system. So, when I install kernel-3.23, It won't be replaced when kernel-3.24 is available in update path. I have to manually install the later/updated one.

But Ubuntu partially handles this problem by using an empty `linux-image-generic` package. This package's description says

> This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel image
>    available.

So, when you update this package, this will bring newer 3-24 kernel in my system. But the older one will still be there. And those will accumulate until you removed them manually. That's why so many people have insufficient space problem in `/boot`.

This is true only for Ubuntu maintained generic kernel only. Mainline kernels don't even have this kind of upgrade mechanism. So, You're the person responsible for maintaining the versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add PPA:  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa`
2. It will asks you for password, so type the password and hit Enter.
3. Now you need to type the following command: `sudo apt-get update`.
4. Type the following command to check did you add Kernel properly: `apt-cache showpkg linux-headers` and hit Enter.
5. On the list in the Terminal will be appear latest kernel version if you have add the properly commands.
6. Finally, type the following command  to update your Kernel: `sudo apt-get install (WRITE headers from step 5) --fix-missing` .
7. Reboot

Comment: I'm worried about my kittens... `The quality of these packages is such that you had better know what you're doing. Don't come crying to the kernel team if it kills all of your kittens.`

Comment: It is better to install latest mainline kernel from: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, *I think* that if I install mainline kernel it **will** be "updated" once the newer official one gets released, but only because grub will be updated. So there always be one additional kernel in the system, but I can live with that for now.